# Hardware SMS gateways?

Tags: gateway

Where can I find some hardware SMS gateways (GSM modems?)? [SMSEagle's](https://smseagle.eu/store/en/devices/9-61-smseagle-nxs-9700-3g.html#/27-extended_warranty-2_year/35-plug_type-us) seem good, but I'm looking for something cheaper and without many bells and whistles.

The [SIM800C](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B087Z6F953) below claims to "Support 2G 3G 4G SIM Card", but I don't think it does; I am looking for something it, though, but for 4G LTE or 5G:

[image: SIM800C]

Comment: What’s the planned use case? Might be cheaper to use a parallel tech.

Comment: @JMY1000 To send out many SMSs rapidly. I've seen things like [SIM900A (which isn't LTE or 5G)](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/q/13683/95138), but I need something that works with 4G LTE or 5G, preferably with an SMA antenna connection.

Comment: Do you really need 5G, 4G. SMS is available even in GSM (2G) standard?

Comment: @RomeoNinov True, but I don't think 2G is available in my area. My particular SIM card only supports 4G LTE and 5G.

Comment: Geremia, using customer grade SIM may raise fraud alarm in mobile operator. Mass SMS servers usually are based on custom agreement. But you can check this, its 4G, a bit cheaper and support more than one SIM: https://ejointech.shop/products/ejoin-4g-8-port-sms-machine-4g-gsm-modem-8-sim-card-multi-sim-lte-ussd-8-port-gsm-modem-4g-sms-modem-api

Comment: Also above support SMPP

Comment: @RomeoNinov I'm using a Tello SIM; [their terms](https://tello.com/terms) don't mention limits for number of SMS messages.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150969/discussion-between-romeo-ninov-and-geremia).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [SIM7600X-H](https://www.simcom.com/product/SIM7600X-H.html) device fits the requirements; it's 4G LTE (Cat. 4) and works in North America.

See [Waveshare.com's SIM7600X 4G Module wiki page](https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/SIM7600X_4G_Module).